# Is there a common naming convention for custom trait/attribute model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, naming-conventions

I am designing an app where user can define traits/attributes for objects.

I was planning to go like this

```
class AttributeName extends Model
{
    //
}

class Attribute extends Model
{
    public function attributeName()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('AttributeName');
    }

    public function job()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Job');
    }
}

class Job extends Model
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Attribute');
    }

    public function getAttributeValue($attributeNameId)
    {
        return $this->attributes->where('attribute_name_id', $attributeNameId)->first()->value ?? ;;
    }
}
```

Unfourtunately, this gives me hard time as `$this->attributes` has another meaning for Laravel models. So `Attribute` is not a very good name for these things.

Naming it `trait` won't go well in PHP either. So what should I name this? Is there any common name that reflects semantics as well as attribute or trait does but doesn't conflict with other uses in Laravel and PHP?

Comment: Naming is always hard, I would just prefix attribute with object_ if that were me

Comment: I had a similar issue to this a while back and I ended up going with "properties" instead of "attributes". If I ever get stuck like this I'll try and google synonyms for the word and see if any suitable solutions come up.

Comment: @RossWilson "properties" is very good, thank you!